# Whitenoise + Django + Cloudfoundry - http 500 when compression is enabled

Tags: python, django, predix

I've successfully deployed **Django** with **Whitenoise** on Cloudfoundry except for the compression. If I set on my `settings.py` to enable compression:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

I get a 500 error and nothing on my `cf logs`. Please not that I don't have SSH access nor/heroku as this is running on **Predix**.

My **settings.py**:

```
STATIC_URL = "/media/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'itcave/media'),
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

**wsgi.py**:

```
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "itcave.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Please also note that all my static files are stored within a `media` folder at the same level as my `settings.py` file.

Adding `web: python itcave/manage.py collectstatic --noinput` on a line before my run command in `Procfile` didn't work. `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is correct because when `DEBUG = True` everything runs fine.

Comment: Have you changed any logging settings?  Can you configure the settings to email you when a server error occurs?  Without any error messages or logs it'll will be difficult to debug.

Comment: What type of logging would you suggest? And where?

Comment: You can define a list of admin emails to receive 500 server errors. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#admins

I would presume you haven't changed the logging much, but here is a link to the documentation on logging in django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/  You could change the logging configuration to log to a file, the console, and email yourself.

Comment: When `DEBUG=True`, there's no need in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, fyi. In terms of your issue, it could be helpful to know what exactly caused the app to crash. A good idea would be to set up an error tracking app, like Rollbar (saas) or Logstash (self-hosted), so that you get more insights. So, waiting for more info :)

Comment: I did. I have Kibana monitoring my logs and the only error I get is a HTTP 500.

Comment: was so excited when I saw this question cuz it is exactly my situation, but so sad when I saw it was unanswered. +1 to the question at least.